# North Atlantic Oscillation seasonal index calculation

Tags: r, formula, weather

I need to find the formula to convert monthly NAO, Scand, EUWR, and other similar climatic indices to seasonal and annual.

`NAO <- c(1, 0.5, 1, 0, -1, -0.5, 0, 1, 0, -1, 2, 3)`

NAO index for 12 months from https://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/data/teledoc/telecontents.shtml

I need to calculate the JFM, JFMA, JFMAM, JFMAMJ indices for January + February + March; January + February + March + April, and so on... I suggest using R for this task.

**An important note:** seasonal is not just the mean, that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want always the cumulative ones, you can use the

```
cumsum
```

function. It works like this:

```
cumsum(NAO)

 [1] 1.0 1.5 2.5 2.5 1.5 1.0 1.0 2.0 2.0 1.0 3.0 6.0
```